# LINQ to SQL failing to update when there is a trigger

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a program that uses LINQ to SQL to update some tables, it is a very simple update i just set a "Active" connlon to 1.

```
else if (obj.Active == 0)
{
   Debug("Found user, but inactive setting to active.");
   obj.Active = 1;
```

I also have some delete and inset logic, but there are no problems there.
The problem is that the SubmitChanges() throws a exception sayint

> 1 of 20 Updates failed

No other information.
Now though some debugging have i found that when my trigger on the database is active do i get this error every time, but when it is disabled dose it all run fine.

This is the trigger.

```
USE [CbsMatrikel]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[LastUpdated]    Script Date: 04/04/2011 10:28:18 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      JEFE
-- Create date: 19-04-2010
-- Description: FullTextSearch field
-- =============================================
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[LastUpdated] ON [dbo].[account] 
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS

set nocount on

update account 
set lastupdated=getdate(),
FullTextSearch = firstname + ' ' + lastname + ' ' + official_email_address + ' ' + UserName + ' ' + cast(matrikel_id as varchar)
where matrikel_id in (select matrikel_id from inserted)
```

I think the problem is that it tests the data and the FullTextSearch field have been changes so it thinks there are some kind of error, but i am not sure.
Have any 1 experience this problem before or know how to fix this?
I am not able to alter the database or triggers, as it is part of a much bigger system.

Comment: Have you tried to profile the SQL that Linq generates and execute that in the DB to see if your tigger gets any errors?

Comment: Yes there are no errors, all executes are just fine.